# How to change background colour of SmallTopAppBar, CenterAlignedTopAppBar, MediumTopAppBar and LargeTopAppBar

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

How can a color resource be used to change the background colour for a MD3 top app bar in Jetpack Compose?

Understandably, a `colors` property is available but it's not clear what to use for the above.

**Color.kt**

```
val MyColor = Color(0,5,5,255)
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
MediumTopAppBar(title = {Text(text = "")})
```

Comment: What type of data does the `colors` property expect?

Comment: `TopAppBarColors`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `colors` parameter is supposed to be used like so.

There's usually a `Default` Companion for these things, which provides a convenience function for modifying colors. For example, the default companion for Top bar colors is just `TopAppBarDefaults`.

Since you are referring to medium bars, we'll use the following

```
TopAppBarDefaults.mediumTopAppBarColors(
containerColor = Color(...) //Add your own color here, just to clarify.
)
```

These functions usually provide a `containerColor` and a `contentColor` parameter by default.

Solving your problems is... Super-easy, barely an inconvenience.

Comment: I don't follow.

Comment: This is the way to **modify** the defaults. The `Color(...)` I typed there is your own color, whichever you wish for the background of the top bar to be

Comment: Sir you are not learning from your mistakes. You asked this previously as well. I pointed you just need to store it in a variable ABOVE the Composable declaration, and then you can use it. Also, `colorResource` is not the correct way of handling colors and theming in Compose. They are supposed to go in the Theme.kt file, but that's beyond the scope of this question. Just before calling your Composable, do something like `val a = colorResource(...)` then use pass `a` as the `containerColor`. Try to retain this info in memory. Just asking everything and not learning won't likely help you much.

Comment: That's a separate question, sir. Is the current one resolved? Just access the resource as I described above and please let me know.

Comment: How to change this for the whole app instead of just one composable? Can this be done in the theme?

Comment: Look at the source of the Composable in concern to find which colour it picks up by default. Most likely it's the surface material color. So, just modify that one colour and you're good to go. If you don't want to modify a color used extensively by many Composables, just create a new color in your custom theme Composable, then simply create a custom Composable for the appbar, reading that custom variable from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `material3` and changing background color doesn't work, there is an issue in `androidx.compose.material3:material3`, and you need to upgrade it to `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha06` or newer versions to fix the background issue in `mediumTopAppBar` or `largeTopAppBar`.